# php.ini file doesn't work even its values changed on phpinfo

Tags: php

I have created my own `php.ini` file on `Cpanel`, and added `max_file_uploads` 100 into `php.ini` file (default is 20).
I check the `max_file_uploads` by `<? phpinfo(); ?>`
It changed to 100, but i still can upload only 20 files.
Anyone here can help me? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Has the server been restarted?

Answer (score -1):

Have you restart the apache ?

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/changes-made-to-php-ini-do-i-have-to-restart-apache.16539/